# Question on webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio

Tags: javascript, html, safari, css

Which all browsers will understand or rather apply CSS rules for the following statement;

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
//CSS Styles
}
```

Also what will be the difference if "only screen" is used above insted of screen i.e.

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    //CSS Styles
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule will be applied for all webkit-based browsers. You can see a list here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#WebKit-based_browsers (most important chrome and safari).

About the word only W3 says:

> The keyword ‘only’ can also be used to
>   hide style sheets from older user
>   agents. User agents must process media
>   queries starting with ‘only’ as if the
>   ‘only’ keyword was not present.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: check this one also link http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/a/css3-media-queries.htm

Comment: Just to re-confirm -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0 would apply to both Windows Safari as well as Desktop Safari also ?