# Is it possible to target chrome by html or media query only

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

this is the media query:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1024px)" href="desktop.css"/> 

<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 1023px) and (max-width: 1025px)' href='ipad.css' />
```

so that i get different style in size of 1024px but this worked on all browsers except chrome the new style appears in size of 1041px

is there any way to target chrome only to give it ipa style in different size

Answer (score 12):

The following can be used to target CSS for Chrome (and Safari, as both are WebKit based):

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
   /* CSS rules */
}
```

See [Question on webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815897/question-on-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio)