# Override default font-size of password inputs in Chrome to match Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

Chrome renders passwords smaller than Firefox. If I manually increase the font-size of a password input element in Chrome to match Firefox, then the caret height will be increased too, which I don't want. What's the workaround to this?

Comment: I imagine this is what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/exbFb/

Comment: Did you test it in both browsers? 2em looks bigger in Firefox. =

Comment: Of course; it's a measurement of a font-height. You said in your question that you increased the font-size but it increases the "caret height" (what I think you mean the height of the input element). "This is what you mean" meant "a demo of what you've tried".

Comment: I guess I meant the height of the font. The height of the input element is 40px in both browsers. Is there a way to have both display the same font height and caret height at the same time?

Comment: Here's a list of all of the `-webkit-*` properties: http://css-infos.net/properties/webkit `-webkit-text-security` specifies the type of symbol to use. You might be able to find a font with a `disc` that's bigger in relation to it's text letter height (meaning it would display larger).

Comment: This uses `-webkit-text-stroke-width` to [manipulate the visible size of the `disc`](http://jsfiddle.net/exbFb/2/). The only "problem" is that you need to apply the `letter-spacing` "fix" only on `-webkit`, but there's not a `-webkit-letter-spacing` vendor property. So if you can add that code only for Chrome, you're home-free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go (using a [media query to select Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897063/is-it-possible-to-target-chrome-by-html-or-media-query-only)... *and Safari*, which I don't have to check):

```
<input type="password" class="pass" value="dfjlfsdkljf"><br>
<input type="password" value="dfjlfsdkljf">​

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .pass {
        -webkit-text-stroke-width: .2em;
        letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    }
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/exbFb/3/

And a blanket selector, to affect a `input[type=password]` elements:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    input[type=password] {
        -webkit-text-stroke-width: .2em;
        letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    }
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/exbFb/4/

Comment: This ruins the placeholder. Any way we can avert this?