# CSS Media Query(@ media)

Tags: css

I have used `@media screen and not (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)` i my CSS file. My question is regarding the value specified i.e "0" in this case. How will a change in value affect my jsp page that references the above CSS file?

Also I read some where that, we can use the above media query for Webkit detection. If so, how? And will there be a problem if we change the value to "0.75 or 1"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question on webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815897/question-on-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio)

Answer (score 0):

I have reference for your problem, hope the link [CSS Media](http://brettjankord.com/2012/11/28/cross-browser-retinahigh-resolution-media-queries/) may help you